# Visual Studio Code silently doesn't connect to marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code, marketplace

Fresh install of vs code on fresh xubuntu 20.04.

Marketplace themes and extensions don't show up in search. vs code does not recommend the Python extension when opening files with .py extension.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~$ sudo apt purge code
~$ sudo apt autoremove
~$ sudo snap install vscode --classic
```

Fixed it.